# Append an array element to begining of a sorted Eloquent ::list array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a list of items in database table of a structure:
id, name.

I need to populate a select box with items sorted by their names along with "All" element with an id = 0 as the first one. What is wrong is that the element doesn't appear in a list box at all.

Controller method:

```
public function getItems(){

$items = Item::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->lists('name', 'id');
$items_all = array(0 => 'All');
array_merge($items_all, $items);
return View::make('items')->with('items', $items);
}
```

and a view:

```
{{ Form::select('item_id', $items, Input::Get('item_id'), array('class'=>'form-control')) }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_merge` returns the new array, so you have to assign the return value to `$items`:

```
$items = array_merge($items_all, $items);
```

Or you can bring it down to this syntax if you want to:

```
$items = array_merge(['0' => 'All'], $items);
```

To **preseve the order** of your array items you can use this:

```
$items = $items_all + $items;
```

Comment: That's was my mistake. I was doing that before, but I'm getting completely unsorted list now..?

Comment: What does unsorted mean? can you add a `var_dump` of `$items` before and after `array_merge` to your question?

Comment: Unsorted by name. They have renumbered by id

Comment: How about `$items = ['0' => 'All'] + $items;` instead of `array_merge`?

Comment: Instead of using array_merge, I need to use $items = $items_all + $items; That solves all my problems here

Answer (score 0):

After updating

array_merge($items_all, $items)

to

$items = array_merge($items_all, $items)

all select box elements got displayed, including 'All', but array_merge renumbers elements, so I used:

$items = $items_all + $items;

as @lukasgeiter suggested at the same time, so I chose his answer as final.